# Optimal control theory: Unclear dependence of control input on Lagrangian

Tags: optimal-control, euler-lagrange-equation

[Here](http://liberzon.csl.illinois.edu/teaching/cvoc/node52.html)
I do not understand the sentence

> Note that even if $L$ does not depend on $u$, the cost $J$ depends
>   on the control $u(\cdot)$ through $x(\cdot)$ which is the trajectory
>   that this control generates.

How can an input $u$ generate a trajectory when it is *not* present in $L$?
It seems that $u$ generates $x$ just by the fact that it is not present somewhere else!

Comment: After a bit of perusal of your link: The ODE being solved has the form $\dot{x} = f(t, x, u)$, so the control function $u$ (generally) affects the solution. By contrast, the functional $J$ isn't involved with _determining_ the solution $x$, but only with _measuring the cost_ of a pre-existing $x$. Even if the running cost $L$ doesn't explicitly depend on $u$, the solution $x$ generally does, and $L$ explicitly depends on $x$. Consequently, varying $u$ varies $x$, which changes the cost $J$.

Answer (score 1):

**Q:** *How can an input* u *generate a trajectory when it is not present in* L *?*

**A:** Simply by being present in the differential equation that defines the trajectory (along with the initial conditions).

Example:

$$\dot{x} = u(t), \; x(0) = x_0$$

The solution to this is

$$x(u(t), t) = x_0 + \int_0^t u(\tau) \text{d}\tau$$

You could choose the Lagrangian to not **explicitly** depend on $u$

$$L = x^2,$$

but it would still do since $x$ does. So does the cost $J$.